# How can I pre-select a product variant based on user profile?

Tags: user-profile, plugin-craftcommerce

I have a product variant that a user can choose from. It looks like this:

```
<select name="purchasableId" class="form-control">
    {% for purchasable in product.variants %}
        <option {% if purchasable.stock <= 0 and purchasable.unlimitedStock == false %}disabled {% endif %} value="{{ purchasable.purchasableId }}"
            {% if currentUser is defined and purchasable.myCustomField in currentUser.userField %}selected{% endif %}>{{ purchasable.myCustomField.label }} &ndash; {{ purchasable.price|currency(cart.currency) }}</option>
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Where I'm stuck is this:

```
purchasable.myCustomField
```

Should (and does) equal this:

```
{{ currentUser.userField }}
```

I know it's a syntax problem... just not sure where I'm off.

**EDIT**

To test, this is what the data looks like:

```
purchasable.myCustomField  // this is a drop down value is "blue"
currentUser.userField      // this is a checkbox that has the value "blue" in it
```

Comment: What FieldTypes are `purchasable.myCustomField` and `currentUser.userField`?

Comment: `purchasable.myCustomField` is a drop-down & `currentUser.userField` is a checkbox group. So I am trying to see if `purchasable.myCustomField` is in `currentUser.userField`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkboxes fields (and other multi-select fieldtypes) return a [MultiOptionsFieldData](https://craftcms.com/classreference/fieldtypes/MultiOptionsFieldData) instance, not an array.

This should work:

```
{% if currentUser.userField.contains(purchaseable.myCustomField) %}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. You are spot-on, I was approaching it as an array. Thank you!